# I am unable to search imported test cases from excel to Zephy Scale in Jira?

Tags: testcase, jira-zephyr

I have imported test cases to Zephyr Scale from Excel, but I am unable to search those test cases in Jira ? Tried searching with title, key, test case number but unable to search them? What do I do?

I tried searching the test cases (imported from excel to Zephyr Scale) but nothing was found

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.